# Deviant VS Pervert (sexually)

Tags: difference

I was wondering what is the difference between a "deviant" and a "pervert" when it comes to sexually unacceptable or immoral behavior or character.
I know that "deviant" often is used to talk about people who are different from what is socially or sexually acceptable, while a "pervert" only refers to someone who is sexually inappropriate.

Comment: Perversion and deviancy are two separate concepts thought they are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sexual context, "pervert" and "deviant" mean the same thing: Someone who does not follow the accepted rules of moral sexual behavior. Perhaps someone would make a technical distinction between the two words but in normal usage, they're essentially synonyms.

You are correct that "pervert" applies only to sexual behavior while "deviant" can apply to other sorts of behavior. It is somewhat curious that the verb "pervert" can be used in non-sexual contexts, but not the noun. Like you could say, "This reporter publishes lies. He has perverted journalism." But you wouldn't then call him a pervert.

"Deviant", on the other hand, can be used to describe a person who breaks non-sexual rules. Like you could call a kidnapper or a murderer a "deviant".

Note that both words are pretty strong and are not normally used for minor infractions. Someone who rapes children is a pervert. Someone who flirts with women other than his wife is not normally called a pervert. Of course what is a sufficiently serious office to warrant being called a pervert is a matter of opinion.

Similarly with deviant. A murderer is a deviant. Someone who exceeds the speed limit is not. Unless you are trying to say that exceeding the speed limit is a horrible offense in the same league as murder.

Comment: Not all deviants are perverts, as in perverse.